# How to get HTML element from another component in angular?

Tags: angular

I have two components called tabs component and series component. The html for tabs component is as follows

```
<div class="row">
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:16px;" (click)="draw()">Update</button>
</div>
```

and in ts file I have a method called draw() { }

In Series component html I have a text field.

```
 <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:10px">
                <label for="xOffset">X Offset</label>
                <input type="text" id="xOffset" style="width:70px;" value="1"/>
            </div>
```

On Draw() in tabs component if I have get HTML element of the text field in series component, How do I get it? I need to display a pop over on the text box. I tried var htmlele = $('#xOffset').html(); but I did not get anything.

Comment: How are the two components related to each other?

Comment: <tabs> <series /></tabs>. Series is inside tabs.

Answer (score 0):

In the tabs component, you can create a reference to the series like this:

```
@ViewChild(SeriesComponent) series: SeriesComponent;
```

You can then access any of the items on that component.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html

I have not done this before, but it appears that if you add a tag reference on that input `<input ..... #xOffset />`, you should be able to use the ViewChild on the Series component as well:

```
@ViewChild('xOffset') xOffset: any;
```

Then, using the ViewChild on the tab object to reference series child object, you should be able to access it through this way.

Comment: what specifically are you trying to get out of xOffset?

Comment: Can you post the code in tabs that you tried that did not work?  I'm still not clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: var target = document.getElementById("xOffset"); I got it like this and used.